# What is the time and space complexity for iteratively generating all subsets of a given array?

Tags: java, data-structures, time-complexity, subset, space-complexity

I have this code for generating the number of subsets of a given array. In each iteration of the `for` loop, I make copies of all the arrays and add a new element to them.]

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>>subsets=new ArrayList();
        subsets.add(new ArrayList());
        int pos=0;
        while(pos<nums.length){
int currentSize=subsets.size();
        for(int i=0;i<currentSize;i++){
            List<Integer>copy=new ArrayList(subsets.get(i));
            copy.add(nums[pos]);
            subsets.add(copy);
        }
       pos++;
        }
        return subsets;
    }
```

What is the time and space complexity? I understand that the number of subsets is 2^N but shouldn't the time taken be more than that?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the time complexity of the `subsets()` function is `O(N * 2^N)` (where N is the length of the input array `nums`). When we ignore `List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList(subsets.get(i));`, the time complexity reduces to `O(2^N)`. However, considering the `List<Integer> copy = new ArrayList(subsets.get(i));` line, the worst-case time complexity becomes `O(N)` for each iteration of the inner loop, and the overall estimate of `O(N * 2^N)` seems appropriate.

Regarding the space complexity, the `subsets()` function requires `O(N * 2^(N-1))` space (where N is the length of the input array `nums`).

To calculate the total number of elements in all the subsets of an array of length N, you can use the formula for the sum of powers of 2.

For a set with N elements, the number of subsets (including the empty set) is 2^N. Each subset may have a different number of elements ranging from 0 to N. To calculate the total number of elements in all the subsets, you can sum the number of elements across all possible subset sizes.

The formula to calculate the total number of elements in all subsets is:

Total Elements = `0 * C(0, N) + 1 * C(1, N) + 2 * C(2, N) + ... + N * C(N, N)`

The simplified formula for the total number of elements in all subsets is:

Total Elements = `N * (2^(N-1))`